# TinyMCE draggable templates

Tags: drag-and-drop, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE version 4.

I also have a couple of html templates defined in my web project.

Now, I would like to make those templates draggable within textarea, so I would like to keep the style of the template and be able to move drag-and-drop/move it.

Does anybody know if it is achievable by using TinyMCE component?